# Oracle novice - can't login with username/password

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I just installed Oracle 11g, and when I try to work with SQLPLUS, after I put the username/password, it says "invalid username/password". The only way to log in is using "sqlplus as / sysdba". But I want to login with the correct username/password which I put during the installation phase, since I want to use them in a JPA project. Should I add another username/password after the installation? If yes, how can I do this? (First time user in Oracle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CREATE USER user_NAME IDENTIFIED BY password`

```
GRANT CONNECT , RESOURCES TO USER_NAME
```

Comment: I wrote "CREATE USER test IDENTIFIED BY test", "GRANT CONNECT , RESOURCES TO test", but again when I start Sqlplus it gives me invalid username/password

Comment: CREATE USER username IDENTIFIED BY apassword;

GRANT connect to username; try this

Comment: Try to provide full connection URL, e.g. sqlplus user/password@//localhost:1521/XE  (JDBC URL format is different but you can find it in docs too)

Comment: Problem solved, I wrote C##test for username (it seems a new feature in c12) and it worked